# Error codigo target frame

Tags: html, wordpress

no puedo encontrar donde esta el error porque no funciona el frame.
El widget es:

```
<html>
<frameset>
<frame name="iframe13" src="blank.html">
</frameset>
</html>
```

y el link es:

```
<a href="{{post.post_link}}" target="iframe13">{{post.post_title}}</a>
```

Este link se abre en una nueva ventana, no funcionando el frame...

Muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar un poco más tu código por favor? Como lo planteas, me hace suponer que el enlace va dentro del archivo blank.html, en cuyo caso no debería abrirse en una nueva ventana.

Comment: El archivo blank.html quiero que aparezca de base en el frame, antes de hacer click en un enlace. El link <a href> esta dentro de una grilla. El frame esta en la misma pagina de la grilla. Gracias!

Comment: `frameset` y `frame` se consideran obsoletos y han sido eliminados del estándar HTML a partir de HTML5. No deberías estar utilizándolos.